# Generating colored and labeled lines with dynamic groups using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have a data frame with variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. I have `a` as my x value, `b` as my y value, and `c` as the group the value belongs to. I can plot each group by doing

```
ggplot(myDataFrame, aes(x=myDataFrame$a, y=myDataFrame$b, group=myDataFrame$c)) +
geom_line()
```

So I wan't to be able to assign a unique color to each group and label each group dynamically without knowing the groups or the number of them beforehand.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html).

Comment: @lukeA Why? This is not a bug issue, I am just trying to figure out how ggplot works.

Comment: Well, just think about it for a minute. If you provide an example, many people can play around with the issue and test things out very easily. Otherwise everyone has to construct the code themselves. Note that also the [R tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) asks you to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geom_line(aes(color = myDataFrame$c))
```